# Compressing non-minified JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression, minify, filesize

I'm not sure if there is a tool to do this but thought I'd ask.

We are building a Javascript library based on jQuery. As it grows the filesize is becoming quite big.
We release both a minified and non-minified version. Or clients want the non-minified version for development as it helps them debug. However, as said, the filesize is quite large now.

Are there any tools that can do some cleaning or compressing without minifying to at least reduce the filesize a little? Maybe simple things like reducing some needless whitespace or formatting the code a little?

Of course in production they will use the minified library but even in DEV they have complained of the large file-size, though we cannot get around that while still adding functionality.

Thank you!

Comment: jsmin has an option to allow throwing out all whitespace except linebreaks. The result is only (# lines*1byte) extra chars compared to a full minification, but the lines numbers in error message are preserved; they aren't all on line #1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google's closure compiler http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/ 
It supports not only minifying but also allows to remove the whitespaces & prettyprint

Comment: Nice answer, especially since it has post information so they could set up an automated minify.  Hell, they could even do it via a script include that automatically minifies if the date/time on the js file has changed.

Comment: Yep, and should the project be on the java domain, there is also the possibility to use a maven plugin to do it on build [https://github.com/jlgrock/ClosureJavascriptFramework](https://github.com/jlgrock/ClosureJavascriptFramework).